# Kinesis vs SQS, which is the best for this particular case?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-kinesis

I have been reading about Kinesis vs SQS differences and when to use each but I'm struggling to know which is the appropriate solution for this particular problem:

- Strava-like app where users record their runs
- 50 incoming runs per second
- The processing of each run takes exactly 1 minute
- I want the user to have their results in less than 5 minutes
- A run is just a guid, the job that processes it will get al the info from S3

If i understand correctly in kinesis you can have 1 worker per shard, correct? That would mean 1 runs per minute. Since i have 3000 incoming runs per minute, to meet the 5 minute deadline would mean i would need to have 600 shards with 1 worker each.

Is this assumption correct?

With SQS I can just have 1 queue and as many workers as I like, up to SQS's limit of  120,000 inflight messages.

- If 1 run errors during processing I want to reprocess it a few more times and then store it for further inspection.
- I don't need to process messages in order, and duplicates are totally fine.

Comment: Do a single message is process only by a single worker, or multiple works can process the same message? Also what happens with the msg after it is processed? It should stay  in a "queue" for possible processing, or removed from it?

Comment: @Marcin 1 worker per message, after it's processed i no longer care about the message.

Answer (score 1):

> 1 worker per message, after it's processed i no longer care about the message

In that case, a queuing services such as **SQS should be used**. Kinesis is a streaming service, which persist a data. This means that multiple works can read messages from a stream for as long as they are valid. Non of your workers would be able to remove the message from the stream.

Also with SQS you can setup [dead-letter queues](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-dead-letter-queues.html) which would allow you capture messages with fail to process after a pre-defined number of trials.